# VBA Excel : filter with "or" condtion between 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel, filter, excel-2007

I have 2 columns (A and D) in my sheet of 10 columns (A-J) with 2 kinds of values : "OK" or "NOT OK". I want to filter to have all the lines with at least one "NOT OK". I also want it the filter (at the title which is row(1)) to appear automatically after running the macro so that I can use it afterwards. However, my code doesn't work.

```
with wb1.Sheets(3)
    .Range("A1:J1").AutoFilter
    .Range("A1:J1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="NOT OK", _ Operator:=xlOr, Field:=4, Criteria1:="NOT OK"
End with
```

Is this doable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want the filter to **show** the NOT rows or **hide** the NOT rows??

Comment: Keep in mind that `AutoFilter` is a toggle, so if you use it twice in a row, you turn it on and then immediately turn it off.

Comment: The first auto filter activate it and the second one is adding the filter, I always did that that way. But if you add a blank autofilter after that, it will remove everything.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I want the lines with at least one "NOT OK".

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to add a new column with a formula checking all you requirements, after that you can filter on that new column.

Comment: All right. If I do a while loop to check the two columns of every line, how could I hide the lines I don't want in filter(lines with 2 "OK") ?

Answer (score 0):

Advanced filters can set complex criteria. We can use temporarily an available to place the filter range then clear it.

```
With wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
  .Range("AA1:AB1").value = Array("ColA", "ColJ")
  .Range("AA2:AB2").value = Array("NOT OK", "")
  .Range("AA3:AB3").value = Array("", "NOT OK")

  .Columns("A:J").AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, .Range("AA1:AB3")
  .Range("AA1:AB3").ClearContents ' clear it after dome with it
End With
```

The same idea can be applied with a normal `Autofilter` though, using temporarily some unused column to generate the filter condition as boolean. For example, using column `AA` (=27)

```
With wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
  .Range("AA2:AA1000").Formula = "=OR(A2=""NOT OK"", J2=""NOT OK"")"
  .Range("A1:AA1000").AutoFilter 27, True
  .Columns("AA").Delete xlToLeft
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to read more on the Internet to understand all but it seems like a smart idea.